# How to make sure a line of code is executed after a loop ends PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I want to execute a line of code behind a foreach but I have to be sure that the foreach has finished. How can I know that? Or is this the default behavior?

Thanks to whoever can help

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $default, 'directory' );
}

$term = get_term_by( 'name', '- Default', 'directory' ); // Run this being sure the foreach has finished.
wp_delete_term( $term->term_id, 'directory' );
```

Comment: Try adding a bool before foreach $finished_foreach = false;  then within foreach change it to true, then use if else to run the code you want after finished_foreach is true.

Comment: PHP is executed sequentially. There is no way the `$term = ...` line can be executed before the `foreach` completes (whether it is a natural end of the loop or from a `break`)

Comment: My concern is that let's say in a scenario where there are 10k posts, the foreach will take a second or more... The code after the foreach will wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you’re using a specific asynchronous extension (although these extension faked asynchronous mode), PHP runs synchronously and it executes all code and loops before moving to the next operation. So in this case it will complete the loop before moving onto the line AFTER the loop.

In fact, if you script takes too long to complete the loop it will throw a timeout error (depending on your PHP configuration). So if you have 100k iterations, your loop will still complete before moving to the next operation.